# Iterate through properties of a object literal

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following code to save some values to the local storage and display it afterwards as a list. The problem I have is with displayRecipes(). It only displays the recipeName value and everything else is undefined. As you can see I store all recipes in localStorage.recipes with the recipe name on the top level and all the other values as "sub-properties" like this: {'recipeName: {'other values and properties'...}}. 
I'm fairly new to JavaScript so I just thought 'undefined' means that the variables have not been initialized correctly. I'm initializing and assigning them in addNewRecipe() but by the time I want to display them they're already stored in local storage.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
function addNewRecipe() {
    var recipeName = $('#recipeName').val();
    var recipeType = $('#recipeType').val();
    var recipePersonsCount = $('#recipePersonsCount').val();
    var recipeTime = $('#recipeTime').val();
    var recipeContents = $('#recipeContents').val();
    var recipeInstructions = $('#recipeInstructions').val();

    // Checks if recipes variable already exists
    // If yes: get content, parse it, add new data to array and store it again
    // If no: create new variable and store it
    if (localStorage.recipes) {
        var getRecipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('recipes'));
        var newRecipe = getRecipes;
        newRecipe[recipeName] = {'recipeType': recipeType, 'recipePersonsCount': recipePersonsCount,
                                 'recipeTime': recipeTime, 'recipeContents': recipeContents,
                                 'recipeInstructions': recipeInstructions};
        localStorage.setItem('recipes', JSON.stringify(newRecipe));
    } else {
        var recipe = {};
        recipe[recipeName] = {'recipeType': recipeType, 'recipePersonsCount': recipePersonsCount,
                                'recipeTime': recipeTime, 'recipeContents': recipeContents,
                                'recipeInstructions': recipeInstructions};
        localStorage.setItem('recipes', JSON.stringify(recipe));
    };
};

function getRecipes() {
    var existingRecipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('recipes'));
    return existingRecipes;
};

function displayRecipes() {
    var recipes = getRecipes();
    for (var key in recipes) {
        if (!$('#rec').val()) {
            $('#recipeList').add('<ul id="#rec">' + key + '</ul>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + key.recipeType + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + key.recipePersonsCount + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + key.recipeTime + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + key.recipeContents + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + key.recipeInstructions + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Try `recipes[key].recipeType` etc instead. `key` is the name of the recipe, but you need to access that key _on the object_ in order to get its specific recipeType, for example.

Comment: I need to see exactly what `recipes` has in it. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: If you are storing multiple recipes and each recipe is an object, you should store them as an array of recipe objects, like this `[{ recipeType: 'a', recipeTime: 1 }, { recipeType: 'b', recipeTime: 2 }, { recipeType: 'c', recipeTime: 3 }]`. It is much easier to consume them in this format. You gain access to all the array methods, including sort, and it is also faster.

Comment: Thank you! I was just accessing them the wrong way, recipes[key] worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing your `object` values wrong.

Change

```
function displayRecipes() {
    var recipes = getRecipes();
    for (var key in recipes) {
        if (!$('#rec').val()) {
            $('#recipeList').add('<ul id="#rec">' + key + '</ul>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + key.recipeType + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + key.recipePersonsCount + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + key.recipeTime + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + key.recipeContents + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + key.recipeInstructions + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
        }
    }
};
```

to

```
function displayRecipes() {
    var recipes = getRecipes();
    for (var key in recipes) {
        if (!$('#rec').val()) {
            $('#recipeList').add('<ul id="#rec">' + recipes[key] + '</ul>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + recipes[key].recipeType + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + recipes[key].recipePersonsCount + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + recipes[key].recipeTime + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + recipes[key].recipeContents + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
            $('#rec').add('<li>' + recipes[key].recipeInstructions + '</li>').appendTo(document.body);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over objects, either make sure to use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to filter:

```
var o = { ... };
for (var p in o) {
  if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    // process o[p]
  }
}
```

or use the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) that filters for you:

```
for (var p in Object.keys(o)) {
  // process o[p]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed in your code:

```
newRecipe[recipeName] = {
    'recipeType': recipeType, 'recipePersonsCount': recipePersonsCount,
    'recipeTime': recipeTime, 'recipeContents': recipeContents,
    'recipeInstructions': recipeInstructions
};
```

You don't need to use apostrophes **unless** the key contains characters such as `-` or numbers.

This is valid:

```
var object = {
    firstname: 'Bob'
}
```

This is invalid:

```
var object = {
    first-name: 'Bob'
}
```

But, this is valid:

```
var object = {
    'first-name': 'Bob'
}
```

This is invalid:

```
var object = {
    0: 'Bob'
}
```

But, this is valid:

```
var object = {
    '0': 'Bob'
}
```

Your code will still work if you change it to this:

```
newRecipe[recipeName] = {
    recipeType: recipeType, recipePersonsCount: recipePersonsCount,
    recipeTime: recipeTime, recipeContents: recipeContents,
    recipeInstructions: recipeInstructions
};
```

You can write it like that, but normally, we might list them because it's more clear:

```
newRecipe[recipeName] = {
    recipeType: recipeType,
    recipePersonsCount: recipePersonsCount,
    recipeTime: recipeTime,
    recipeContents: recipeContents,
    recipeInstructions: recipeInstructions
};
```

Now, here's where it gets sweet. You can use ES6 `Object Literal Shorthand Syntax`. If an object's property key is the same as the variable name assigned to its value, you can do this:

```
newRecipe[recipeName] = {
    recipeType,
    recipePersonsCount,
    recipeTime,
    recipeContents,
    recipeInstructions
};
```

Try it out in your code :)

To visualize it a bit better, run this sampler pack:

```js
var test = '100% neat';
var bonus = true;

var cool = {
    test,
    bonus
};

console.log(cool);
console.log('Confirmed:', cool.test);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely something I will try out.